# animate quivers on basemap

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, matplotlib-basemap

I'm trying to animate some quivers on a basemap using Numpy, but the data is on differents files (E and N gps displacements). In first place, I try to load all the files with np.loadtxt and glob, and the result it's an array (or matrix, at this point I don't know) of this style:

```
    bla = [array([1,2,3,....,1000]), array([1,2,3,....,1000]),....]
```

What I want, is to animate quivers of the displacement of the gps data in a basemap, for that I made this code:

```
import numpy as np
from glob import glob
from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation

estaE = glob('/Users/joaquinjulve/Documents/Universidad/Herramientas/Examen/GPS_E/*e.out')
gpsE = [np.loadtxt(a) for a in estaE]
estaN = glob('/Users/joaquinjulve/Documents/Universidad/Herramientas/Examen/GPS_N/*n.out')
gpsN = [np.loadtxt(b) for b in estaN]
estaciones = np.loadtxt('/Users/joaquinjulve/Documents/Universidad/Herramientas/Examen/estaciones.coord.out', usecols=(1,2))
gpsupE = np.asarray(gpsE)
gpsupN = np.asarray(gpsN)
desE = [a.T[1] for a in gpsE]
desN = [b.T[1] for b in gpsN]
t = [c.T[0]for c in gpsE]
tup = np.asarray(t)
desupE = np.asarray(desE)
desupN = np.asarray(desN)

map = Basemap(projection='merc', 
          llcrnrlat=-45, llcrnrlon=-75,
          urcrnrlat=-25, urcrnrlon=-60, resolution=None)
map.drawparallels(np.arange(-90,90.,4), labels=[1,0,0,0])
map.drawmeridians(np.arange(-180,180,4), labels=[0,0,0,1])
map.bluemarble(scale=4)
lat = estaciones.T[0]
lon = estaciones.T[1]
x, y = map(lon, lat)
Q = map.quiver(x, y, desupE, desupN, color='red')

def update_quiver(Q, x, y):
U = desupE
V = desupN
Q.set_UVC(U,V)

anim = animation.FuncAnimation(map, update_quiver, fargs=(Q, x, y),
                           interval=10, blit=True)
plt.show()
```

Comment: Currently `update_quiver` will do nothing because your `desupE` and `desupN` arrays don't change between calls. There's nothing in your code to suggest *how* you want the quivers to change.

Comment: Read this [post](https://github.com/matplotlib/basemap/blob/master/examples/animate.py), may be it'll help